# Why does my code giving me "mismatch in formal parameter list"?

Tags: data-structures, parameters, stack

I am trying to transfer the elements from a source stack to a destination stack. And for that i am using some variables and making sure that get transfered into the destination stack in the same order as they were in the source stack. I wrote the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

template <typename S>
void transferByVar(stack<S> &source, stack<S> &dest)
{
    int var = 0;
    S topVal;
    if (source.empty())
        return;
    else if (source.size() == 1)
    {
        dest.push(source.top());
        source.pop();
    }

    int size = source.size();
    while (count != size)
    {
        topVal = source.top();
        source.pop();
        while (source.size() != count)
        {
            dest.push(source.top());
            source.pop();
        }
        source.push(topVal);
        while (!dest.empty())
        {
            source.push(dest.top());
            dest.pop();
        }
        ++count;
    }
}

int main()
{
    stack <int> s1;
    stack<int> s2;
    s1.push(0);
    s1.push(1);
    s1.push(2);
    s1.push(3);
    s1.push(4);
    s1.push(5);
    s1.push(6);
    s1.push(7);
    s1.push(8);
    s1.push(9);
    transferByVar(s1, s2);
    int size = s2.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << s2.top() << " ";
        s2.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but it gives me an error of C2563: mismatch of formal parameter list. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What is "count" in the while loop? You've declared nothing in the scope.

Comment: Oh i got the error. but still it is not producing the required result.